# String replace in FTL with a specific word

Tags: freemarker

I need to replace a specific string in a URL in FTL.

Code 1:

```
<#assign pageUrlWithParams= "https://sample.com/category?filter=low&navParam=Appliances&skrLocale=en_US&t=1"/>
<#if pageUrlWithParams?? && pageUrlWithParams != '' && pageUrlWithParams?contains("skrLocale")>
    <#assign pageUrlWithParams = pageUrlWithParams?replace('skrLocale','')/>
</#if>
${pageUrlWithParams}
```

Code 2 :

```
 <#assign pageUrlWithParams= "https://sample.com/category?filter=low&navParam=Appliances&skrLocale=en_FR&t=2"/>
    <#if pageUrlWithParams?? && pageUrlWithParams != '' && pageUrlWithParams?contains("skrLocale")>
        <#assign pageUrlWithParams = pageUrlWithParams?replace('skrLocale','')/>
    </#if>
    ${pageUrlWithParams}
```

I need to remove "skrLocale=en_US" and "skrLocale=en_FR" from pageUrlWithParams.

Known text is "skrLocale", using this I need to remove "skrLocale=en_US" and "skrLocale=en_FR".
Because of en_US and en_FR, i dont know how to take that that part after equals.

Some suggest an answer please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions (`'r'` as 3rd parameter to `?replace`) is the key. Note that due to the complexity of URL syntax, we need to handle two edge cases (`skrLocale` is the first parameter, and `skrLocale` is the only parameter), which the below function fulfills. However, it doesn't handle `%xx` escapes in the parameter name (which you might don't care about):

```
<#function removeSkrLocale url>
  <#return url?replace(r'([&\?])skrLocale=[^&]*&?', '$1', 'r')?remove_ending('?')>
</#function>

${removeSkrLocale(pageUrlWithParams)}
```

Of course you can do this without `#function` as well, directly inside the `${}`, but it's reusable and more self documenting this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Freemarker function](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_function.html) (this is a simple version, can be improved)

```
<#function remove_param_if_value_equals pageUrlWithParams paramName, paramValues >
    <#if pageUrlWithParams?has_content && pageUrlWithParams?contains(paramName)>
        <#list paramValues as paramValue>
            <#local paramNameAndValue = paramName + "=" + paramValue />
            <#local pageUrlWithParams = pageUrlWithParams?replace(paramNameAndValue,'')/>
        </#list>
    </#if>
    <#return pageUrlWithParams />
</#function> 


<#assign pageUrlWithParams= "https://sample.com/category?filter=low&navParam=Appliances&skrLocale=en_US&t=1"/>
<#assign pageUrlWithParams = remove_param_if_value_equals(pageUrlWithParams, "skrLocale", ["en_US", "en_FR"]) />
${pageUrlWithParams}
```

The code that does the business remains isolated and can be altered/improved later on.

(For example there is that double "&" that could be cleaned)

Comment: "en_US", "en_FR"  can be anything. we should not keep that as static value. Can you please check this

Comment: "en_US", "en_FR" are arguments for the function, the last 3 lines are an example... your example

Comment: you are passing that as static value. if en_Nr comes this will not work.

Comment: you said: Known text is "skrLocale", using this I need to remove "skrLocale=en_US" and "skrLocale=en_FR" , rewrite your question

Comment: if you want to remove the param skrLocale regardless of its value you have to split the queryString in params (separated by &), loop over them and re-build the queryString skipping skrLocale

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about FTL. But if you need to replace parameter **skrLocale** in your URL, I think below is good pattern you can use:

```
(skrLocale(.*?)&)
```

With (.*?) is called lazy, it match from **skrLocale** to nearest **&**. Therefore, with your case, it will match **skrLocale=en_US&** and **skrLocale=en_FR&** .

Comment: Will this work if `skrLocale` is the last parameter in the URL?

Comment: It not work if `skrLocale` is the last parameter in the URL. If skrLocales is the last parameter, you can use pattern 
`((&skrLocale(.*?))(&))` And you need to use group 2 to replace the parameter.